# Inequality Concerning Positive Elements in a C$^{*}$-algebra of Norm at Most One

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, gelfand-representation

I am studying the GNS construction and in part of a proof in one of the theorems along the way (theorem 3.3.3. in Murphy's book), the following statement is made:

> Now suppose that $a$ is positive and $\|a\|\leq 1$. Then $u_{\lambda}-a$ is hermitian and $\|u_{\lambda}-a\|\leq 1$.

Here, $(u_{\lambda})_{\lambda\in\Lambda}$ is some approximate unit of $A$. The fact that $u_{\lambda}-a$ is self-adjoint is obvious, since both $u_{\lambda}$ and $a$ are positive, but I am unsure how to deduce that $\|u_{\lambda}-a\|\leq 1$. Is it true that in general for two positive elements, each of norm at most one, their difference is of norm at most one?

Thank you.

Comment: Isn't it straightforward to verify that the spectral radius of the difference is at most $1$? Then one just needs to exploit that the norm of a normal element is its spectral radius.

Comment: I'm not sure how to verify that the spectral radius of the difference is at most $1$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since I cannot find the answer (which has given here already a few times) I will just post it: For any two positive elements $a,b$ of norm less or equal to one, we get:
$$
-1 \leq -b \leq  a - b \leq a \leq 1
$$

Comment: Thank you. That hit the spot.